# How to set rich text property when creating memo field in DAO?

Tags: ms-access, dao

I'm creating a table with a memo field in DAO.
However, I don't know how to set/create the [rich text property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eba9b887-63c1-457a-874b-4aeb4243b865/using-dao-to-set-the-rtf-property-of-a-field?forum=accessdev) for the field.

The following code gives a run time error:

```
Sub CreateTable()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field2
Set db = CurrentDb

' Create table
Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef
tdf.Name = "myTable"

Set fld = tdf.CreateField("memo_field", dbMemo)
fld.Properties("TextFormat").Value = acTextFormatHTMLRichText   '<- getting error here
tdf.Fields.Append fld

db.TableDefs.Append tdf
db.TableDefs.Refresh
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Somebody in a [forum](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1684976.html) suggested something like this,

```
fld.Properties.Append fld.CreateProperty("TextFormat", dbByte, acTextFormatHTMLRichText)
```

but I was not able to implement this.
I guess I just go the syntax wrong. What would be the correct way to implement this?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have trouble appending a property to a field that is not yet appended to a `TableDef`.

Try:

```
Set fld = tdf.CreateField("memo_field", dbMemo)
tdf.Fields.Append fld
tdf.Fields(fld.Name).Properties.Append fld.CreateProperty("TextFormat", dbByte, acTextFormatHTMLRichText)
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I had to create the property after `db.TableDefs.Append tdf`